# Determine if the textbox contains the same value as any other textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am using winforms using C#, I want to check if one of my textboxes has the same value as any other textbox in my textbox array. The user enters values inside the textboxes and if any duplicate value is entered, an error is displayed. When I use the textchanged event handler with the for loop to iterate through the entire array, it is checking every single text box instead of comparing the text box that only has the text changed to the other text boxes.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        TextBox[,] textBoxArray = new TextBox[5, 5];
       
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBoxArray[0, 0] = textBox1;
            textBoxArray[0, 1] = textBox2;
            textBoxArray[0, 2] = textBox3;
            textBoxArray[0, 3] = textBox4;
            textBoxArray[0, 4] = textBox5;
            textBoxArray[1, 0] = textBox6;
            textBoxArray[1, 1] = textBox7;
            textBoxArray[1, 2] = textBox8;
            textBoxArray[1, 3] = textBox9;
            textBoxArray[1, 4] = textBox10;
            textBoxArray[2, 0] = textBox11;
            textBoxArray[2, 1] = textBox12;
            textBoxArray[2, 2] = textBox13;
            textBoxArray[2, 3] = textBox14;
            textBoxArray[2, 4] = textBox15;
            textBoxArray[3, 0] = textBox16;
            textBoxArray[3, 1] = textBox17;
            textBoxArray[3, 2] = textBox18;
            textBoxArray[3, 3] = textBox19;
            textBoxArray[3, 4] = textBox20;
            textBoxArray[4, 0] = textBox21;
            textBoxArray[4, 1] = textBox22;
            textBoxArray[4, 2] = textBox23;
            textBoxArray[4, 3] = textBox24;
            textBoxArray[4, 4] = textBox25;
            
        }
        private void newGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    textBoxArray[i, j].Text = "";
                    textBoxArray[i, j].ReadOnly = false;
                }
            }
            int randomNum = rand.Next(0, 5);
            textBoxArray[randomNum, randomNum].Text = "1";
        }

        private void ifTextChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Set textbox with Value 1 to Read Only

            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    if (textBoxArray[i, j].Text.Equals("1"))
                    {
                        textBoxArray[i, j].ReadOnly = true;
                    }
 
                }
            }
           
        }
```

Comment: This is not a good idea in the `TextChanged()` event as the user may not be done entering their value but you will already have made the TextBox ReadOnly even though the next keystroke may change the state of things.  As it is, you don't have any code to turn back OFF the ReadOnly state previously turned on.  How will they continue entering keystrokes if you prematurely lock them out?...

Comment: @Idle_Mind I have a new game method that resets everything, I wanted to solve the duplicate issue first and then go back and fix that issue with the 1 integer

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the problem, but `object sender` in the TextChanged event is the TextBox that has changed. You can simply cast the sender to TextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this same text changed event handler on all the textboxes:

```
private void Any_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
  if(this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Any(tb => tb != sender && tb.Text == (sender as TextBox).Text))
   MessageBox.Show((sender as TextBox).Text = "Dupe";
}
```

Comment: You'd need to exclude the sender textbox from the search otherwise you'll always get a match.

Comment: Fixed, thanks @Idle_Mind